# Wordpress portfolio posts not appearing on page

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, portfolio

Before updating the wordpress version & theme version (Avada) to the latest  versions, everything was ok. After I updated those two, I have the following problem:

I have 20 portfolio posts published on category "Botosani":

http://prntscr.com/6zu82q

But only 2 portfolio posts are showing on my page.

After the updates, I see my address bar a different url for portfolio posts:

http://prntscr.com/6zu9dc

How do remove the `?portfolioid=`

How can I have all my "Botosani" category posts showing on the page?

Comment: I tried some little plugins, didn't work. Here's the page code: http://pastebin.com/YU1pSr6e

Comment: I think it's an ajax problem, or something like that. Check this page, click on "Botosani" category: http://zigzagprinromania.com/blog/gazde/

Answer (score 0):

Ideally after taking updates all the core files gets updated. So if you have done any changes in any core file. You would have lost it.

If your theme provide any settings then you should look any option to change number of post to show if not then look for your category template.

If you are not sure about template then I recommend to go through wordpress template hierarchy.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

For second part of your question go to setting/permalink in your wordpress dashboard and select the right permalink and save it. 
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed ! I changed just 1 featured image on 1 portfolio post and then all posts appeared.